# intent.getextra() is receiving null and intent.hasextra() is not working in the second activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm trying to send data continuously to another activity using intent.

In the first activity,

**MainActivity.java**

```
class sender extends AsyncTask <void, void, void>
{       
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   {
      while(true)
      {
           if(!intent.hasextra())
           {
                String data = dataBuffer;
                intent.putextra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,data);  
           }
       }
   }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         //  intent.putextra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,"Test data"); --> This is working 
         startActivityForResult(intent, 333);

    }

}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
class receiver extends AyncTask <void, void, void>
{
    while(true)
    {
         if(intent.hasextra())
          {
             resultString = intent.getextra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
             mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ,resultString 
                                             ).sendToTarget();
             intent.removExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
          }
    }
}
```

When Debugging, both threads are executing but the if-conditions inside while(true) are not satisfied.

Note: When Before StartActivityForResult(), putExtra is sending the data and in the secondActivity I could receive the data.

Please tell me why the data is not sent and received in both doInbackground().

Comment: is there any possibility for `dataBuffer` becoming null ?

Comment: No I checked, it does have a string always.

Answer (score 0):

> When Debugging, both threads are executing but the if-conditions
>   inside while(true) are not satisfied.

Look at the code you have posted, this is because your both `AsyncTask` is running simultaneously and hence while receiving Asynctask goes to `doInBackground()` it didn't find the `Intent` values. You better want to delay the execution of your second `AsyncTask`.

On the other note, I would strongly suggest changing your approach, as it will lead to many issues in future. There is other better way to communicate between two activities.

Comment: I introduced delay and still, no data is received in the second activity. Please tell me your suggestion to communicate between two activities.